# MVC3 - How to handle url string which can add end of with from user input ( browser addressbar )

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, xss

I think question is clear. I want to handle url strings which can be added by user.

Example;

```
http://download.cnet.com/windows/script alert('hello') /script
```

or

```
http://download.cnet.com/windows/aaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

As you can see in examples, cnet handle these inputs and redirect user to custom 404 file.

I'm working on mvc3 razor, it's something with controller I suppose, but I can't make it.

*Extra Information:
What I want to do; I want to handle or external string which can be added end of the url.
Another example; http://www.yazilimdevi.com/yazilimdevi/aaaaaaaaa
As you can see, if user input "aaaaaa" to end of url; he/she see "Server Error in Application" which was prepared by IIS. I want to create a custom page, and redirect all users who added unknown path, string or script...*

Thanks...

Comment: What is the possible scenario you're trying to protect your app (users?) from? URLs like those you provided will do no harm if just typed by user in address bar. Could you also provide some code?

Comment: Sergey, thank you very much for your comment. I updated my question. Please look at "Extra Information" section. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement special handling for this scenario then you may want to add new route using `/{*arbitrary_url_part}` scheme. For example, route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "SampleRoute",
            "constant_path/{*variable_part}",
            new {controller = "ErrorController", action = "ShowError", variable_part = ""}
            );
```

will match all those urls:

`http://Server_url/constant_path/` (variable_part=="")

`http://Server_url/constant_path/aaaaaaaaaaaaa` (variable_part=="aaaaaaaaaaaaa")

`http://Server_url/constant_path/script alert('hello') /script` (variable_part=="script alert('hello') /script")

etc. no matter how much slashes or other special symbols user puts in. For reference, see [MSDN: ASP.NET Routing - Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern)
.

If you don't want to bother yourself with implementing all this stuff and only want to show a fancy 404 page to user then you might consider using standard ASP.NET feature - [Custom error pages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Other strategies on handling such requests can also be found in [This blog post](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/).

**UPDATE**

If you want to go the first way, you'll also have to add controller and view for displaying some custom error page. If you take the same names as in route you'll have to add following to your project:

1. File `Controllers/ErrorController.cs` containing class `ErrorController` with method `ShowError`, like this:

   ```
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   namespace Your_app_name_here.Controllers
   {
       public class ErrorController : Controller
       {
           public ActionResult ShowError(string variable_part)
           {
               return View((object)variable_part); // Cast to object is required here
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. File `Views/Error/ShowError.aspx` - a simple HTML view to display error information, like this:

   ```
   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
   <HTML>
   <HEAD><TITLE>Error page title here</TITLE></HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <H1>variable_part = <%=Model.ToString()%></H1>
   </BODY>
   ```

Comment: I don't get it. I wrote and change-try and change-try your example code in Global.asax.cs in "public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)" method - But there is nothing works. Here is what I wrote; routes.MapRoute(
                "Error",
                "{controller}/{ * . * }",
                new { controller = "ErrorController", action = "Index" }
           );

Comment: @LostInLib: My answer was not a complete code snippet, sorry :(. Of course you also need to add corresponding ErrorController with action ShowError and possibly create a simple view for error display. I'll update my code in a few mins.

Comment: Sergey, thank you very much for your full tutorial. -Spasibi :) but I'm still getting "Server Error in '/' Application." message, when I try these urls; http://localhost:8956/aa , http://localhost:8956/error/aa ... http://localhost:8956 is working correctly but when I edit url, server error app. shows up. Maybe my question is not clear, but that's what I want to handle...

Comment: I made it ok, http://localhost:8956/error/aa now can handle with @Model.ToString(); ok, I click to "accep your answer" icon and thank you very much for your help.